Necessary steps for shipping a .dll that includes the Open Cascade library
I am using Visual Studio with a template from "Siemens" that is called "C++ ODK2.5" for developing a C++ application that can run on Windows while a software CPU has an inteface to this application.
I developed an application that can evaluate step files and translates drill hole data to coordinates for a kinematic to drill.
The program works perfectly in a normal exe application without the odk.
The ODK works without including my code and the includes in c++.
#include "stdafx.h" //ODK-Preset
#include "ODK_Functions.h" //ODK-Preset
#include "ODK_StringHelper.h" //ODK-Preset

#include <algorithm> //normal include that works
#include <filesystem> //normal include that works

// as soon as i include anything here it breaks the execution of the ODK
// and doesnt load the .dll in the CPU anymore
#include <AIS_Shape.hxx>
#include <BRepAdaptor_Curve.hxx>
#include <BRepBndLib.hxx>
#include <BRepBuilderAPI_Transform.hxx>
#include <BRepGProp.hxx>
#include <GProp_GProps.hxx>
#include <IntCurvesFace_ShapeIntersector.hxx>
#include <TopExp_Explorer.hxx>
#include <TopoDS.hxx>
#include <BRepExtrema_DistShapeShape.hxx>
#include <STEPControl_Reader.hxx>

What i would like to know is if it is an error on my side. Since the prebuild Open Cascade library works on my execute file is there anything I need to do differently if im compiling into a .dll file.
I tried copying the dll's necessary to the target system in the same folder as my generated .dll, I tried different project settings.
The dll loading fails with:

CPU function library could not be loaded for the following reasons:

the DLL file is not a CPU function library
a 64-bit application should be loaded into a 32-bit system
Dependencies to other Windows DLL files
could not be resolved
Check whether the release build of the CPU function library is being used.
Check whether the "Visual C++ Redistributables" are installed for the Visual Studio version you are using. The CPU does not support the
ODK version used.


Also. The Siemens support said they have no Idea. I escalated it to their highest support level...

I think what you've failed to mention here is what exactly goes wrong when you run this from a DLL. Clearly is's not working but some indication of what happens instead might help.

Since you haven't specified your problem, it's not possible to give a specific response.   But, generally speaking, it will depend on how your DLL uses (interfaces to) the "another library".     You might need to build  your DLL so it statically includes relevant parts of the library.   If the "other library" is a DLL, that is dynamically loaded by your DLL, then you will need to ship both DLLs (and ensure they are installed in a location, so your DLL can find and load the other one).

@john I edited the error message from the CPU-Error while loading the dll.

There is a tool called "dependency walker" or plain "dependencies" that can load a DLL and verify these conditions in isolation of your program.

Use this tool https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies
